# What will load faster. Converted Variables or $_POST variables?

Tags: php, performance

I'm fairly new to PHP and still don't know some of the most basic basics of PHP so bear with me.

When writing a script; IE: (Plz ignore syntax errors)

```
if isset($_POST['name']) {$Name = $_POST['nsme'];}
```

When using this name in the page, which way is better and loads faster??

A:) `echo $Name. ' went to the river';`

B:) `echo $_POST['name']. 'went to the river';`

Obviously this is a fictional example, I'm just wondering which way is better whether it be an echo or any other function and if anyone wouldn't mind chiming in on this, I'd be most appreciative and I thank you all once again.

Comment: You are wasting the time optimizing things that does not really matter in your case

Comment: In most cases you should care more about sanitizing your input, then performance differences. So option (B) is rather vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously

```
echo $_POST['name'].' went to the river';
```

would be faster, as you are skipping one step of assigning the post variable to a php variable.

Comment: still $name would be one lookup for the variable itself and $_POST['name'] would be a lookup for the $_POST var and then for the 'name' key.... but that's microtuning what is mostly useless

Comment: even then B will load faster in this case because it is skipping the time of assigning to a php variable. Eve though it is microsecond it is worthy.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about speed don't worry you can use any of them ,deference  significantly low but creating variable which is used only once is not a good idea

However if you are doing

```
$Name = $_POST['nsme'];
```

and using `$name` variable i am sure you want to read about [**Singleton variable**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_variable)

and if you are using $name at other place too its perfectly

Comment: Thanks @NullPonyPointer, SO I'm interpreting that as: If I'm going to use it more than once, create and use a variable correct??

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $_POST['name'].' went to the river';
```

Will be faster as you are skipping one step.

However if you need to use `$_POST['name']` multiple times, second approach will be better.

Answer (score 0):

A direct variable access is always faster. At least the zend lexer has not recognize for dimensions...

At least for multiple uses...

(use always an isset()-check at least else you'll have notices.)

Comment: Hi everyone and thanks for all of your input. @NullPonyPointer, You raise a good point in stating I shouldn't create a variable for a single use and I think that's great advice but I'm working on a classifieds script and looking through the code I keep seeing multiple uses of things (IE $_POST['Boat_Color']) so I was wondering if these occurences are best left as is or if I should convert all of these. I hope that makes sense...

Comment: If you use it multiple times, it's faster to assign it to a variable. (in the same context)

Comment: I also often wonder about the difference in MySQL Query's (Working off of $table['Boat_Color_Column'] or converting that t0 $BoatColor and using that variable throughout the site

Comment: It depends on how often. Say three times in the same context and it's better to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have var `$foo` and make:

```
$bar = $foo;
```

It doesn't create another copy of `$foo` in memory until you change `$foo` or `$bar` so you will have almost same var for both.

You will have same speed, but `$bar` will look better than `$_POST['bar']` and with it easier to work.